# Deleting obsolete menu types

Tags: joomla-3.x, extensions, menu, xml, extension-update

While programming a Joomla extension, I experimented with Menu Types, however while editing/deleting/adding types in the default.xml it doesn't delete the previous ones.

So while I only have 1 menu type defined in the default.xml it still shows all the 'old' ones.

How can I delete those? I've looked in the database but can't find the reference the these menu types.

Default.xml:

```
<metadata>
    <layout title="COM_GCMAILS_MAILING_VIEW_DEFAULT_TITLE">
        <message>COM_GCMAILS_MAILING_VIEW_DEFAULT_DESC</message>
    </layout>
</metadata>
```

But the menu still shows:
[image]